# DNSMASQ Not recieving DHCP requests/ DNSMASQ Not sending

Tags: dhcp, fedora, pxe-boot, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I have a Fedroa 31 BOX that I'm trying to use as a dhcp server. It doesnt appear to be functioning. I have used dhcping 192.168.1.xxx where xxx is ip address of server and the output is always no answer. Using tcp dump and netstat shows that the port is open on the server and the packet is being received but it appears to be either no ouput or dnsmasq is not receiving the packet. I have replicated this with both firewalls enabled and disabled with same results. cant seem to find any useful logging information for DNSMASQ but systemctl and var.log only say that it started up fine with no indication as to whether it has recieved any packets. DNSmasq.conf posted below

```
listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.1.159
interface=enp2s0
domain=fios-router.home
dhcp-range=enp2s0,192.168.1.2,253.255.255.0,2h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,192.168.1.159
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
server=1.11.1.1
dhcp-option=28,192.168.1.255
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for menu.", 60
pxe-service=x86PC, "Install CentOS 7 from network server 192.168.1.59", pxelinux
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-async
log-queries
log-dhcp
~
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite likely you’re running firewalld (enabled by default).

Use the following command to enable DHCP in the firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=dhcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```