# dnsmasq DHCP not working, not replying to DHCP requests

Tags: centos, dhcp, dhcp-server, tcpdump, dnsmasq

I have setup dnsmasq as DHCP server on a CentOS VM, however it is not replying to DHCP requests. What could be the issue? Following is the configuration and tcpdump logs.

```
interface=ens224
listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,172.17.11.1
dhcp-range=172.17.11.10,172.17.11.50,24h
dhcp-option=option:router,172.17.11.1
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.leases
```

Following is the DHCP request which I can see on the interface ens224 by tcpdump:

```
17:42:01.409959 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 12:34:56:00:11:02, length 300
```

Following is the status of dnsmasq:

```
# systemctl status dnsmasq -l
● dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-01-05 17:41:11 GMT; 1s ago
 Main PID: 3680 (dnsmasq)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─3680 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -k

Jan 05 17:41:11 Underlay systemd[1]: Started DNS caching server..
Jan 05 17:41:11 Underlay dnsmasq[3680]: started, version 2.76 DNS disabled
Jan 05 17:41:11 Underlay dnsmasq[3680]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth nettlehash no-DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Jan 05 17:41:11 nderlay dnsmasq-dhcp[3680]: DHCP, IP range 172.17.11.10 -- 172.17.11.50, lease time 1d
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1005230/dnsmasq-not-recieving-dhcp-requests-dnsmasq-not-sending?rq=1